# Running batch fine onclick delay

Tags: java, batch-file, jframe, jtextarea

I have a JButton that executes a batch file (ping 192.168.0.5) and outputs the ping result into a JTextArea. It does work when I push the button to run the batch file. The console shows the computer being pinged in realtime just like cmd prompt would, but the after the button click, it waits for the batch file to finish executing and then outputs the entire result all at once instead of in realtime like the console. How can I get the textArea output to run in realtime like the console instead of all at once?

```
JButton btnPingComputer = new JButton("PING");

    btnPingComputer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String line;

            Process p = null;

            try {

                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\test.bat");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                    .getInputStream()));

            try {

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(line);

                    textArea.append(line);
                    textArea.append(String.format("  %s%n", line));

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            try {

                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // textArea.setText("");

        }

    });
```

Comment: You should use the ProcessBuilder class.

Comment: Is your propose from the previous code to run only Ping command or you want to use something else in batch file ?

Comment: I'm using ping as a simple example to get it to run in realtime, but I will be running other batch scripts as well.